# How to export shared container of an iOS App with Xcode6.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, xcode-6.2

In our iOS app we utilize a shared container to share files between our main iOS app and its extension (specifically WatchKit Extension), using `[NSFileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:]` method. For debugging purposes we need to access the content of this shared container, so we've tried to export the whole App container using the Devices window in Xcode:

[image: Screenshot from Xcode]

But, the Shared storage is not included in the container, probably because it sits in a different path on the Device itself.

The question is how can we get the shared container, if this is even possible?

Answer (score 9):

I've been told by Xcode team members at WWDC that this is not possible (at time of writing, Xcode 7.3 & 8 beta 1). I've filed a [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5021353337946112), which I recommend everyone dupe or comment on so we can get this functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Workaround for actual device -

I generally pause the execution of my app and then run following command in **lldb debugger** to copy the desired file from shared container to my sandbox container and then I download the container from Xcode.

> po [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[[NSFileManager
>   defaultManager]
>   containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:GROUP_NAME]
>   URLByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME].path toPath:[[[[[NSFileManager
>   defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
>   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]
>   URLByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME] path] error:nil]

Above might look complex but if you break the above, we are doing 3 things -

1. Get shared container file

   > [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:GROUP_NAME] URLByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME].path
2. Get sandbox document directory path:

   > [[[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME] path]
3. Copy file from Shared container to sandbox

   > [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:SHARED_PATH toPath:SANDBOX_PATH error:nil]

Answer (score 6):

For **Swift 4 - 5** add this to applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)

```
var appGroupIdentifier = "XXXXXXX"
let fromURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroupIdentifier)
let docURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let toURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent(appGroupIdentifier)
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: toURL)
try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fromURL, to: toURL)
```

Then download the app container using xcode.

Comment: I have used this approach. Somehow, my container is always emtpy..

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code to print out in the console the path to my local SQLite database:

```
NSString *groupContainer = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.myapp.mycontainer"] path];
NSString *sqlitePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Database.sqlite", groupContainer];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sqlitePath];
```

I then copy and paste the string in the Finder -> Go to so I go directly to the folder. This works fine in the Simulator but I don't think you're able to access the your iPhone's shared container group from your Mac.

Comment: Thanks @BalestraPatrick, I'm aware of the Simulator solution, but we need a solution for real devices for after-the-fact log crunching from beta tester devices.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your data from the group container to document directory. Then download the app container using xcode.

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(url, toURL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(AppDelegate.applicationUserDirectory()))
```

url here can be obtained using below function of NSFileManager

```
func containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier groupIdentifier: String) -> URL?
```

Comment: your variable here url, what would this be if trying to access the Default location of a realm db i.e. one that's visible under Documents after showing Package Contents?

Comment: @user2363025 you can copy all the contents of container into document directory then choose what you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is creating a backup of your device and then using iExplorer to explore the backup. There are bunch of `AppDomainGroup-*` folders. Though for some reason not all of the files there are backed up (probably because of applied settings to files to be ignored during backup).

Answer (score 0):

Updated Sandy's response to swift in lldb and usage of appGroup

```
(lldb) po FileManager.default.copyItem(at: FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.name")!.appendingPathComponent("filename"), 
to: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!.appendingPathComponent("filename"))
```

Another thing is that you may need to remove file from the app folder if it's been copied before otherwise the command above will fail