# Download shared App Group Container from XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, containers

Is it possible to download a shared app group container with XCode similar to how the sandboxed container is downloaded for a particular app? I haven't been able to find any definitive Apple documentation on this.

Answer (score 4):

Afaik this is not possible with official software. There is also no third party tool I know of to do this.

There are some workarounds that may be helpful to:

- You can access the shared app group folder when testing with the iOS Simulator. [SimPholders](https://simpholders.com) can open the folder directly, so you wont have to search around for it.
- You could copy the contents of your shared app folder to your app’s default folder. This way you can download the contents using Xcode’s Organizer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code of the debugging the app, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727337/how-to-export-shared-container-of-an-ios-app-with-xcode6-2/50281026#50281026) and copy the file to from AppGroup to sandbox container and then download.