# realm commit write error - Can't commit a non-existing write transaction

Tags: swift, database, swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to add a record to a realm DB table.

I have a class Connection which represents a table I need in my DB and have created dynamic vars which are to represent the columns:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import Realm

open class ConnectionState: Object {

    open dynamic var _id : String = NSUUID().uuidString
    open dynamic var a : String = ""
    open dynamic var b : String = ""
    open dynamic var c : Int = 0

    open override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }

    required public init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required public init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }

    required public init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then in my code I am trying to write and commit the write transaction like so:

```
let ConnectionState = ConnectionState()
ConnectionState.a = "a"
ConnectionState.b = "b"
ConnectionState.c = 1
try! self.realm.write {
     self.realm.add(ConnectionState)
}

try! self.realm.commitWrite()
```

When running this code, I am receiving the error:

```
Can't commit a non-existing write transaction
```

What am I missing? Do I need to have inits in my ConnectionState class?
Before adding in the commitWrite, I was trying to view the db with realm browser. I found my device in xCode and chose to download the container but it was empty. Then I thought I needed to add in commitWrite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you called `commitWrite` without having called `beginWrite`. You cannot commit a write transaction because you did not start one. Either start a write transaction or delete the commitWrite line.

1. Start transaction and commit it

   ```
   self.realm.beginWrite()

   self.realm.add(ConnectionState)

   try! self.realm.commitWrite()
   ```
2. Delete commitWrite

   ```
   try! self.realm.write {
        self.realm.add(ConnectionState)
   }
   ```

The [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) have two examples of adding data to the database.

1. Use the `realm.write` method

   ```
   // Use them like regular Swift objects
   let myDog = Dog()
   myDog.name = "Rex"
   myDog.age = 1
   print("name of dog: \(myDog.name)")

   // Get the default Realm
   let realm = try! Realm()

   // Query Realm for all dogs less than 2 years old
   let puppies = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age < 2")
   puppies.count // => 0 because no dogs have been added to the Realm yet

   // Persist your data easily
   try! realm.write {
       realm.add(myDog)
   }
   ```
2. Use `realm.beginWrite()` and `realm.commitWrite()` to start the write transaction and commit data to the database

   ```
   let realm = try! Realm()

   // Break up the writing blocks into smaller portions
   // by starting a new transaction
   for idx1 in 0..<1000 {
     realm.beginWrite()

     // Add row via dictionary. Property order is ignored.
     for idx2 in 0..<1000 {
       realm.create(Person.self, value: [
         "name": "\(idx1)",
         "birthdate": Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(idx2))
       ])
     }

     // Commit the write transaction
     // to make this data available to other threads
     try! realm.commitWrite()
   }
   ```

Comment: I mistakenly added in the commitWrite as I couldn't find any record when searching for my realm db. I have downloaded the container and chosen to show package contents but there is no default.realm for me to open with the browser. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: If you cannot find your file then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465706/how-to-find-my-realm-file/28465803#28465803

Comment: Yes I have followed the instructions in that SO as per my comment above. The problem is that once I get into AppData and documents there is no default.realm. I have set my realm to a specified location as part of an app group container. My realm file path is file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/B4D9C8F6-6A72-4539-A144-6AD622873A0A/db.realm

Comment: You have to follow the path that you just copied

Comment: When selecting showPackage contents from my container, the only folders available are AppData which itself has Documents, Library and tmp. I don't see any folders such as Shared, Containers, AppGroup as per the path

Comment: It would be easier if you just test it on a simulator or ask a new question on SO cause I cannot help you with that. Hope this answer helps solved your problem though.

Comment: Ok I've found the problem. It isn't current possible to view containers of an app group in this way. I don't think : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727337/how-to-export-shared-container-of-an-ios-app-with-xcode6-2

Answer (score 4):

```
try! self.realm.write {
     self.realm.add(ConnectionState)
}
```

This code is somewhat equivalent to (possibly with some additional error handling):

```
realm.beginWrite()
...
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

Which means you're trying to commit your writes twice.

Just change your code like this:

```
try! self.realm.write {
     self.realm.add(ConnectionState)
}

// try! self.realm.commitWrite()
```

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. But when I choose to show Container for my app, there is nothing there? How can I see this record in the realm browser. Testing on device, not simulator

Comment: If your device is connected to your developer machine - you can output the location of the Realm data file (Swift = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL) and then open that using the Realm Browser.